# react native ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, dependencies

The react-native android APP, that I am developping in windows local environment started to stop building a few days ago.  I had warnings about jcenter() being deprecated, which I replaced with maven.  I also had issues related to Slider by react native community,... Finally, I decided to delete files within node_modules, and rebuild them.  Unfortunately, I still had dependencies issues while trying to rebuild.  Anyone can tell me what is wrong, and how to solve it?

Here are the debug log and the APP's package.json:

[Building dependencies error][1]

debug log:

```
# npm resolution error report

While resolving: AwesomeProject@0.0.1
Found: react@17.0.1
node_modules/react
  react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
  peer react@"*" from @react-native-community/slider@4.1.7
  node_modules/@react-native-community/slider
    @react-native-community/slider@"^4.1.7" from the root project
  peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native@0.64.2
  node_modules/react-native
    react-native@"^0.64.2" from the root project
    peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/slider@4.1.7
    node_modules/@react-native-community/slider
      @react-native-community/slider@"^4.1.7" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"17.0.2" from react-native-windows@0.65.3
node_modules/react-native-windows
  peer react-native-windows@"*" from @react-native-community/slider@4.1.7
  node_modules/@react-native-community/slider
    @react-native-community/slider@"^4.1.7" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "react",
    "version": "17.0.1",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "AwesomeProject",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "path": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/react",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "^17.0.1",
        "from": {
          "location": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "peer",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "*",
        "from": {
          "name": "@react-native-community/slider",
          "version": "4.1.7",
          "whileInstalling": {
            "name": "AwesomeProject",
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
          },
          "location": "node_modules/@react-native-community/slider",
          "isWorkspace": false,
          "dependents": [
            {
              "type": "prod",
              "name": "@react-native-community/slider",
              "spec": "^4.1.7",
              "from": {
                "location": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "peer",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "17.0.1",
        "from": {
          "name": "react-native",
          "version": "0.64.2",
          "whileInstalling": {
            "name": "AwesomeProject",
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
          },
          "location": "node_modules/react-native",
          "isWorkspace": false,
          "dependents": [
            {
              "type": "prod",
              "name": "react-native",
              "spec": "^0.64.2",
              "from": {
                "location": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "peer",
              "name": "react-native",
              "spec": "*",
              "from": {
                "name": "@react-native-community/slider",
                "version": "4.1.7",
                "whileInstalling": {
                  "name": "AwesomeProject",
                  "version": "0.0.1",
                  "path": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
                },
                "location": "node_modules/@react-native-community/slider",
                "isWorkspace": false,
                "dependents": [
                  {
                    "type": "prod",
                    "name": "@react-native-community/slider",
                    "spec": "^4.1.7",
                    "from": {
                      "location": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "^17.0.1",
    "from": {
      "location": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "17.0.2",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "react-native-windows",
      "version": "0.65.3",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "AwesomeProject",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/react-native-windows",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "peer",
          "name": "react-native-windows",
          "spec": "*",
          "from": {
            "name": "@react-native-community/slider",
            "version": "4.1.7",
            "whileInstalling": {
              "name": "AwesomeProject",
              "version": "0.0.1",
              "path": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
            },
            "location": "node_modules/@react-native-community/slider",
            "isWorkspace": false,
            "dependents": [
              {
                "type": "prod",
                "name": "@react-native-community/slider",
                "spec": "^4.1.7",
                "from": {
                  "location": "C:\\Users\\pascal\\Desktop\\AwesomeProject2"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

APP's package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.7",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "npm": "^7.15.1",
    "react": "^16.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.44.1",
    "react-native-color": "^0.0.10",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.23",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-in-app-message": "^1.0.32",
    "react-native-modal": "^12.0.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-generator": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.6.4",
    "realm": "^10.6.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[...errors trying to resolve dependencies after deleting 'node_modules' contents][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSwEm.png

[...errors after yarn, cd android, gradlew clean, cd.., npx react-native run-android][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TFtV.png

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the dependencies before building? if not then run `yarn` to install the dependencies

If done already then try below commands before rebuilding:

On project root run

`cd android && ./gradlew clean`

then start

`npx react-native run-android`

Comment: I did all that, and I have the same problems as before deleting node_modules's contents.  I am gonna add the latest errors I had in the description...